# Prolog list of atoms

Tags: list, prolog, visual-prolog

How to convert this

```
fact( [a,b,c], [d,e,f], ..., [p, q, r] )
```

to a list of these elements?

Result:

```
[[a,b,c], [d,e,f], ..., [p, q, r]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list_fact_args(Fact,List) :- Fact =.. [fact|List].
```

`=..` is a handy predicate that transforms the predicate on the left to a list with predicate name as the first member and its arguments as the latter members. Or a list on a right to the predicate on the left. Here `fact` denotes that it lists only the predicates named 'fact'.

Comment: I don't think Visual Prolog has the `=../2` operator.

Comment: Sorry but how to use this? <br/>
`fact( [a,b,c], [d,e,f], [p, q, r] ).`<br/>
`list_fact_args(Fact,List) :- Fact =.. [fact|List].`<br/>
`list_fact_args(F,L)`<br/>
`No solutions`

Comment: @mbratch Visual prolog does have that operator

Comment: Like this: `list_fact_args(fact( [a,b,c], [d,e,f], [p, q, r] ),L)`. Sorry for being too succinct. I'm new here.

Comment: No problem, and thank you very much!! One more thing (sorry, I'm a newbie to prolog): what if fact(....) is predefined like `fact( [a,b,c], [d,e,f], [p, q, r] ).`

Comment: @balping ok, cool. I was going to suggest it, but I couldn't spot it in their online documentation.

Comment: @balping if you *only* need to get a list of the arguments for a particular predicate whose arity is known, then you can just put the arguments into a list. E.g., if you have `fact` defined as you say, then, given `fact(A, B, C), List = [A, B, C]`, `List` will instantiate to `[[a,b,c], [d,e,f], [p,q,r]]`. Otherwise, using `=../2` is the way to go! It's great fun to work with.

Comment: @aBathologist I mean the user inputs only this: `fact( [a,b,c], [d,e,f], ..., [p, q, r] )` And I have to handle somehow the list

Comment: @balping meaning you don't know the arity (number of arguments) or the functor (e.g., `fact`)? In which case you want to use `=../2`.

Comment: @aBathologist I don't know the number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Get your Prolog Manual or textbook and look up =.. / 2.